# How to post data of selected rows of a dataTable to php controller through an JQuery ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I used this code from https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html to select multiple rows

```
$('#table tbody').on('click','tr', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

This is the initialization for jquery datatable

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //datatables
    table = $('#table').DataTable({ 

        "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
        "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
        "order": [], //Initial no order.

        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            //'copyHTML5', 'csvHTML5', 'excelHTML5', 'pdfHTML5', 'printHTML5'
            'copy', 'csv', 'print'//, 'excel', 'pdf'
        ],
        // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo site_url('person/ajax_list')?>",
            "type": "POST"
        },

        //Set column definition initialisation properties.
        "columnDefs": [
            { 
                "targets": [ -1 ], //last column
                "orderable": false, //set not orderable
            },
            { 
                "targets": [ -2 ], //2 last column (photo)
                "orderable": false, //set not orderable
            },
        ],

    });

    $('#table tbody').on('click','tr', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });
}
```

Now I want to send these selected rows to php controller through an ajax call so I can then create a csv file with these selected rows data.

I created a button which on click calls the following function where the ajax call is made

```
    function create_PO()
    {
        $('#btnSel').text('creating...');
        $('#btnSel').attr('disabled',true);

        var url = "<?php echo site_url('person/create_csv')?>";
        var selectedData = table.rows('.selected').data();
        //console.log(selectedData);
        //alert(selectedData.length);
        newData = new Array();
        for(i=0;i<selectedData.length;i++){
            newData.push(selectedData[i]);
        }
        jsonData = JSON.stringify({data : (selectedData[0].slice(0,5))});
        //console.log(jsonData);
        //newData = $.serialize(newData);
        //console.log(newData);

        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type: "POST",
            data: jsonData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data)
            {
                /*data.forEach(function(e){
                    console.log(e);
                })*/
                console.log(data);
                // alert("sheet created successfully");

                // $('#btnSel').text('create');
                // $('#btnSel').attr('disabled',false);

            },
            /*error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('Error creating file');
            }*/

        });

    }}
```

when I do `echo($_POST)` from the controller, the response is showing empty array.
Also, the `console.log(data)` function in success option of ajax is also not printing anything. Can anybody pls tell me what the problem is? Thanks!

Comment: table.rows('.selected').data(); - where are you getting "tables" from ? This is why you are not posting anything...

Comment: @NorbertBoros table is the datatable. Yo can now see where I got the table from. Check the code

Comment: As documentation suggests, If the answer is correct, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### JQuery part

The reason you are not getting anything in console, is that `success` callback gets the data that is returned by server, not the data which is sent. Try `console.log(jsonData)`.

Also, to analyze sent data, use Network tab on Chrome Developer Tools.

---

### PHP

On the PHP side, you might be passing data in request payload, thats because your form is type of JSON, not `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

To access it use the following instead of `$_POST`:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

### Process JSON

To process your stringified json to array:

```
$processedData = json_decode($data);
```

now you can access your array properties like this:

```
foreach($processedData as $item){
        // do stuff
        echo $item;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I can now see the response as follows `"{\"data\":[\"vipul\",\"mallapragada\",\"male\",\"-\",\"1994-10-25\"]}"`. But how do I access the elements in this structure. Could you please help.